# Appium taking screenshots for failures

Tags: appium, appium-android, takesscreenshot

I'm building android framework using Appium, Serenity and POM model.

I wanna take screenshots if any of the steps failed.

Can anybody help me with code and please let me know where to put that?
Eg I have Pages, steps and stepdefinition class.
Not sure where to implement that?

Comment: Any comments pls?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compare pictures with template by OpenCV library. That's what I do:

1. Add method to `base_page.py`.

   ```
   def compare_image_with_screenshot(self, image_name: str):
       os.chdir('../src/screenshots/')

       with open(f'{image_name}.png', 'rb') as img:
           first_image = base64.b64encode(img.read()).decode('ascii')

       second_image = base64.b64encode(self._driver.get_screenshot_as_png()).decode('ascii')

       return self._driver.get_images_similarity(first_image, second_image)
   ```
2. Use this method in Page Object file.

   ```
   @allure.step('Compare screenshot with template')
   def get_image_comparison_percents(self):
   """
   This method gets screenshot on device with template in repo. Comparison result is percentage of similarity. Test is OK if comparison more than 90%
   """
       result = self.compare_image_with_screenshot(OfflineLocators.offline_stub)
       return result.get('score')
   ```
3. Use step in necessary test.

   ```
   @allure.link(url='https://jira.myproject.tech/browse/TEST-1', name='TEST-1 - Offline stub')
   @allure.title('Offline stub')
   def test_offline_stub(appdriver):

       TourActions(appdriver).skip_tour()
       Navigation(appdriver).open_my_offline_page()

       assert Offline(appdriver).get_page_title_text() == 'Offline'
       assert Offline(appdriver).get_image_comparison_percents() > 0.9
   ```

In result of all of this I get some percentage of pictures similarity. It can be with that percentage what you need. For my tests it is OK.

If you mean screenshots for the test results, just let me know and I can show you example how I did it with Allure.

If you mean usual screenshots in Appium, please provide some mistakes which you catch.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for response. Are you taking about screen comparison? I wanna take screenshots for the test results, that too only if it's failed. Also can u share that for appium serenity framework pls?

Comment: Yes, my example is about screenshot comparison. If you need to get screen shot by failure, I can show example with Allure framework. I add additional answer in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is example to get video if test is failed.

1. conftest.py (in the root directory)

   ```
   @pytest.fixture
   def appdriver():

   driver = config.get_driver_caps()

   if config.IS_IOS:
       driver.start_recording_screen(videoQuality='high', videoType='mpeg4', videoFps='24')
   else:
       driver.start_recording_screen()

   yield driver

   attach_device_log(driver)
   save_screenshot(driver)
   driver.quit()
   ```
2. Save screenshot method

   ```
   def save_screenshot(appdriver):
       allure.attach(
            appdriver.get_screenshot_as_png(),
            name='screenshot',
            attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG
        )
   ```